# Hive create database, Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, hive

I am reading the book `PySpark Recipes A Problem-Solution Approach with PySpark2` 
It connects hive to postgresql. When I run the command

```
hive> create database apress;
```

I am getting the following error.

```
FAILED: HiveException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
```